# javascript too many decimals doing subtractions

Tags: javascript, decimal, arithmetic-expressions

I'm doing a simple subtraction with Javascript and the result doesn't match with the real result:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr><td>Price: </td><td><input type="text" id="price" value="4500.60" onblur="calculatePrecio();"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Discount: </td><td><input type="text" id="discount" value="500" onblur="calculatePrecio();"></td></tr>
</table>

<div id="divTotalAmount"></div>

<script>

calculatePrecio();

function calculatePrecio()
{
    var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
    var discount = document.getElementById('discount').value;

    p = price;
    d = discount;

    totalAmount = p - d;

    document.getElementById('divTotalAmount').innerHTML = "<h1>"+totalAmount+"</h1>";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can you guys help me? In addition I just don't want to know how to proceed, I want to know the reason for this, if possible.

Comment: Perhaps you're wondering: [Is JavaScript's Floating-Point Math Broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Read about floating point arithmetic: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: You can use `.toFixed()`, as the answers suggest, but it's always somewhat perilous to do "money math" with a floating point numeric system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To format the output you can simply used the `toFixed` method.

```
var x = 5.3, y = 3;
var z = (x - y).toFixed(2);
```

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/CC9q9/) is the working jsFiddle.

Comment: Thank you for all the anwsers. It's so strange this about "double precision" but I love learning and I'm very interested on this!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `totalAmount.toFixed(2)` for example .... it will be somthing like this xxxxxxxx.xx